# Can I use same file name in different folder in xcode and how to access it in ios Swift language

Tags: xcode, audio, swift, ios8

I am working on audio player in iOS 8 in Swift language.

I have an audio file name with "apple.mp3" in both male and female voices same audio name. Both files are two different groups, for male male group and for female audio female group. So paths would be male/apple.mp3 and female/apple.mp3.

I am using following code to play an audio file

```
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var currentAudioPath:NSURL!
    currentAudioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioName, ofType: "mp3")!)

    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: currentAudioPath, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.play()

    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

How can I play both audios separately with specific path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, if you have similar file names *anywhere* in the project, no matter how deep in a subfolder, Xcode will complain about duplicate resources.
When you ask for an image by name, Xcode 'sees' the whole project, that's the up side.

In short, no, you cannot have two resources with identical name in the same project. It is advised to give a unique name to each one.

Comment: Thanks for reply @bauerMusic.So can't we give a specific path like male/apple.mp3 to file path?

Comment: I'm guessing(?) that it has to do with compiling everything. The folders are only for convenience really. The one exception (I think) could be the `Documents`, `Library` folders maybe, but you can't really place precompiled resource there. I kind of solved a similar problem by giving the file a directory name. For example: `male.apple.mp3`, `female.apple.mp3`. Folders are really just a unique string that represent a unique  path. (If `male.apple.mp3` isn't working, just use `male_apple.mp3`.